# WPF - UpdateSourceTrigger not fired when using ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I have following style defined for TextBox:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="DialogWindowTextBox">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                                    <Border BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="3" BorderBrush="#99bbe8">
                                        <TextBox  MinHeight="20" MinWidth="150" BorderThickness="0"></TextBox>
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
```

Usage of defined style:

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource DialogWindowTextBox}"  Width="230" DockPanel.Dock="Right"  Margin="4" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding UuidFilter, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Delay=2000}"/>
```

The issue now is that UpdateSourceTrigger is ignored for all TextBoxes for which defined style is applied (UuidFilter property is not updated). Styles are applied for all TextBoxes exactly as defined in the code snippet.

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't put another `TextBox` element in the `ControlTemplate` of a `TextBox`.

What you should do is to replace the `TextBox` in the template with a `ScrollViewer`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="DialogWindowTextBox">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <Border BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="3" BorderBrush="#99bbe8" MinHeight="20" MinWidth="150">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```